# how to select specific words from an string of character

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a line like this

```
#aman#ab179#167#abbash aman battra
```

I want output like this

1. `#aman`
2. `#ab179`
3. `#167`
4. `#abbash`

All the characters having `#` as first letter but I am getting the whole line instead.

This is my code

```
for word in stringWordsArray {
        print(word)
        if word.hasPrefix("#"){
            print("Exists")
            print(word)
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to split the text before checking the prefix. Try `String.split` and `NSRegularExpression`. Then ask something more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you were looking for `split` method of `String`. Here I have written example for you:

```
    let str = "aman#ab179#167#abbash aman battra"
    let separator = "#"
    var arr = str
        .split(separator: Character(separator)) // get array of string separated by `#`
        .map { separator + $0 }// manually add `#`
        .flatMap { $0.split(separator: " ").first } // remove substring separated by " "
    print(arr)
```

Comment: Can't believe we thought in the exact same way. :P

Comment: @InfinityJames  I'll take that as a compliment =)

Comment: this is working but first character is always a '#' character . my string is "Write something Here" and the output is printed as "#Write" which is wrong implementation

Comment: @Abathla Feel free to change `#` on what you want =)

Comment: if I type 'Aman' this will return ["#aman"] to me .. but it should not return anything instead

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
let sentence = "#aman#ab179#167#abbash aman battra"
let words = sentence.split(separator: "#").flatMap { $0.split(separator: " ").first }.map { "#" + $0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
let str = "aman#ab179#167#abbash aman battra"
let arr = str.components(separatedBy: "#")
 for arrayString in arr{
       print("\((String (describing: arrayString).firstWord()!))")
}
```

// for choose first word

```
 extension String {
    func firstWord() -> String? {
        return self.components(separatedBy: " ").first
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you will get exact output using below code

**Swift 4.0**

```
 let temp = "#aman#ab179#167#abbash aman battra"

 var fullNameArr = temp.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces)[0].split(separator: "#")

 var arrData = [String]()

   for word in fullNameArr {
    var temp = word
    temp.insert("#", at: temp.startIndex)
    arrData.append(String(temp))
  }
print(arrData)
```

Comment: Hey @Abathla Did you find my answer helpful?